# Is there a way to keep traps constantly on?

Tags: terraria

In terraria, there are multiple types of traps. My favorite being the flame trap. My question is, is there a way to make an electrical loop or a clock like in minecraft to keep the flame trap constantly on? Or any trap really, just as long as the trap reactivates constantly.

Also, I know that there are timers but I want to integrate the trap into my home security system; it is basically a switch that turns blocks on and off to block entrances as shown below and I can't have the timer constantly turn that on/off every 1/3/5 second(s)

[image: Wiring]
[image: Turned On]
[image: Turned Off]

The other switch (Blue and purple wiring) serve to open only two entrances/exits

Comment: You could just put two switches next to each other, one for walls, one for traps on timers.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk The reason why I need it to be on one is so that once the doors have been closed, the traps activate and give extra protection to the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [timer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Timer) or a [crab engine](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crab_Engine) (a statue-spawned crab trapped in a 1-high compartment with a pressure plate). Timers can be turned on and off just like a switch by right clicking them, so you can enable or disable your home security system whenever you like, or indeed you can use switches and other mechanisms to turn timers on/off.

Comment: can you add a picture with the circuitry?

Comment: @BakedPotato circuitry of what?

Comment: Can you show me the crab engine basically

Comment: @BakedPotato http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crab_Engine and also http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Wire_Creations#Crab_Engine